# Получить список праздничных дней через API

Tags: php

Для одного проекта мне нужно получать актуальные дни, которые в РФ считаются праздничными. В последующем хочется получать праздники стран СНГ.

Откуда можно получить эти данные для последующей обработки на PHP? Например JSON, XML, серилизованный массив?

Comment: А раз в год формировать файлик ручками никак?

Comment: Можно и так, но если этот процесс можно автоматизировать - это лучшее решение. Нашел, например, такой портал: http://data.gov.ru/ Но нужного пока не вижу(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, можно воспользоваться [этим](http://basicdata.ru/api/calend/) сайтом.

Comment: Черт-побери! Это то, что надо!!!

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

Даже вопрошать - "Вас в гугле забанили?" - не хочу.
[Вот](http://www.gooood.ru/holiday.php) список праздников. Запихни в массив, сериализуй/в_JSON/преврати_в_XML и сохрани в файлик/БД.
Выдрать можно регуляркой (прям вижу как @Vlad мне медленно голову откручивает за такой совет), а можно любым HTML-парсером.

Comment: А переносы выходных с января на май вы не учитываете? Это сохранить нельзя )

Comment: @BOPOH, Эм, что? Тем более выходной - не праздник вроде как.

Comment: Мне че-то казалось, что 1-10 января считаются праздничными и их иногда переносят

Comment: @BOPOH, все верно говоришь! Перенос праздничных дней с выходных на будние - не предсказуемая вещь. Насколько я знаю - это контролирует РОСТРУД. Но у них на сайте не нашел выгрузки, только парсить. Можно ли без парсинга...?